# Is this system of three equations solvable in arithmetic operations and root extraction etc

Tags: systems-of-equations

Is this system of three equations solvable in arithmetic operations and root extraction etc?

$$\begin{array}{cl}x + y + z &= a\\
xyz &= b\\
x^3y^3 +x^3z^3 +z^3y^3 &=c\end{array}$$

If the degree of exponents were same , the solution will just be the factors of a cubic $$(t+x)(t+y)(t+z)=0$$

and substitution method will just result a $9$-th degree equation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $x,y,z$ are solvable using arithmetic operations and root extractions.

Let $u = \frac1x, v = \frac1y, w = \frac1z$ and define

$$\begin{align}
A &= u + v + w\\
B &= uv+vw+wu = \frac{x+y+z}{xyz} = \frac{a}{b}\\
C &= uvw = \frac{1}{xyz} = \frac1b\\
p_k &= u^k + v^k + w^k\quad\text{ for } k = 1,2,3\end{align}$$
By [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities), we have

$$\begin{align}p_1 &= A\\
p_2 &= Ap_1 - 2B = A^2 - 2B\\
p_3 &= Ap_2 - Bp_1 + 3C = A^3 - 3BA + 3C
\end{align}$$
Notice $$p_3 = u^3 + v^3 + w^3 = \frac1{x^3} + \frac1{y^3} + \frac1{z^3} = \frac{c}{b^3}$$

$A$ is a root of the cubic equation
$$t^3 - \frac{3a}{b}t + \left(\frac3b - \frac{c}{b^3}\right) = 0$$
Using [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) for depressed cubic,
we can compute $A$ using arithmetic operations and root extractions from
$\frac{3a}{b}$ and $\frac3b - \frac{c}{b^3}$.

Once we get $A$, $u,v,w$ are roots of the cubic equations 
$$t^3 - At^2 + Bt + C = 0$$
Transform the cubic equation to a depressed one and apply Cardano's formula again, we can compute $u,v,w$ (and hence $x,y,z$) using arithmetic operations and roots extractions from $A,B,C$ (and hence from $a,b,c$).

The actual formula for $u,v,w$ will be a nightmare, I will leave the fun to you.

Comment: I already knew the answer haha , I wanted to see a different approach . It is almost similar to my approach ,instead I find an a equation/identity for x^3+z^3 +y^3 in terms of the coefficents which results a cubic equation.Then I cube the equation for the b coefficent.  Now that the exponents are same degree , the equations are just the coefficients of a cubic (t+x^3)(t+y^3)(t+z^3) :)